# Quick NLP in Data Frame column

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, token

I am trying to return a data frame ('word' | 'count') from words in a column of a data frame.

I keep getting both below errors, when I try as a series and as a data frame. Also tried it as a list.

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'
AttributeError: 'List' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Below is my code (modified from an answer found in this site).

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', tokenizer = word_tokenize, ngram_range=(1, 1), min_df = 1)

words = datahitword['clean_word']

X = ngram_vectorizer.fit_transform(words.split('\n'))

vocab = list(ngram_vectorizer.get_feature_names())

counts = X.sum(axis=0).A1

freq_distribution = Counter(dict(zip(vocab, counts)))
print (freq_distribution.most_common(10))
```

Can you guys please help?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run `split` on the list `words`. You can't split a list (or series or dataframe), only the actual strings. If you need to split some of the strings inside `words`, use a list comprehension to access each one individually.

Comment: The 'list' has only individual words. Thats why i was treating it as is.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `words.split('\n')`?

Comment: Turn them into a corpus. Is the split '\n' wrong?

Comment: CountVectorizer is for running on a list of documents. For example, you could make a list of filenames of books then run it on that. It's not for individual words.

Comment: For example:
`books = ['books/book1.txt', 'books/book2.txt']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='books')`

Comment: You are right, it scaped me, I do not need NLP, the words are already individuals. I just need to summarize them (count them). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It scaped me, I do not need NLP, the words are already individuals. I just need to summarize them (count them).